# android r11 ndk is missing clang tool chain

Tags: android, android-ndk, clang, toolchain

Our android applications use multiple shared and static libraries that were pointing to the clang 3.5 tool chain via the `Application.mk` `NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=clang3.5`. We use command line `ndk-build`. A fairly significant update to the android `ndk` to`r11` was just released,  release notes indicate that everything now uses clang and that latest clang is 3.8.    After upgrading to  `r11` the clang tool chain doesn't appear to be anywhere in the updated `ndk`.  My question simply is where do `find/install/update` the missing toolchain(s). All I see in the in the `/ndk-bundle/toolchains/` is ... `android??/x86 .. 4.9`   which is not clang.

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `clang` instead of `clang3.5`.

Comment: That worked. Thank you.  I have to admit when I saw the response I was very skeptical but I bow with humility.  Would you mind sharing why that worked exactly.  I'm still confused about the toolchain since there is only references to the gcc 4.9 toolchain in the r11 ndk directory.

Comment: You're welcome. The NDK resolves `clang` to point to the most recent version of clang so that's why this works in this case.